# Unable to Install Applications or Drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, installation, group-policy

Attempts to install Windows updates, applications or drivers are failing. I suspected it might be a broken Group Policy. But when I tried to open gpedit, I got `Failed to open the Group Policy Object on this computer. You might not have the appropriate rights. Details: Unspecified error` I am the administrator on this machine. I read that I should delete the contents of C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy, but that folder is already empty. How do I fix things so that I can install applications again?

Comment: “When I try to open it” - What exactly is “it”?

Comment: Group Policy Edtior

Comment: The local group policy editor only exists is only on Windows 10 Professional. So are running Windows 10 Professional? What build of Windows 10 are you running?  I have ran into this exact problem when I was running an expired Insider Preview build within a VM.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 Professional 20H2 19402.985

Comment: Yeah; I suspect you have serious system corruption.  Can you run the appropriate SFC and DISM commands to see if that is the case?

Comment: `sfc /scannow
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19042.985

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.`

Comment: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19042.985

[==========================100.0%==========================] No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.`

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information but obviously, it's not system corruption to blame. The only thing I will point out is that you are several weeks behind on updates.  I assume you have considered installing any updates that are applicable to your system and performed a system reboot?